# sed / grep randomly fails to trim a string

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

I am using a bash script that will load content from a text file and extract data accordingly.
Problem is that sometimes extracted data is preceded by a dot.

Code:

```
function str_extract() {
 pattern=$1
 # Extract
 res=`grep "$pattern" $log | sed "s/$pattern//g"`
 # Drop trailing ...
 res=`echo $res | sed 's/[.][.][.]//g'`
 # Trim
 res=`echo $res | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed 's/ *$//g'`
 echo  $res
}

  download=`str_extract "Download: "`
  upload=`str_extract "Upload: "`
```

Data:

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Telecomunicazioni S.p.A. ...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Coolnetwork (Arezzo) [26.09 km]: 111.547 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 2.06 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed...............................................................................................
.Upload: 1.81 Mbit/s
Share results
```

will extract

```
"2.06" #correct 
".1.81" #wrong preceding dot
```

Comment: Ciao concittadino! :-) 1. always enclose variables in double-quotes, so `pattern="$1"` and also all the `echo "$res"` lines (and consider using `printf` in place of `echo`), and 2. prepend your regexs with `.\?` as in `".\?Upload: "` to make provision for the optional leading dot

Comment: Thanks! In Arezzo as a tourist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many regexes and variables.

Get both values:

```
$ sed -n 's/^\.*\(Download\|Upload\): //p' data
2.06 Mbit/s
1.81 Mbit/s
```

Get one value:

```
$ sed -n 's/^\.*Upload: //p' data
1.81 Mbit/s
```

Get one value without "Mbit/s":

```
$ sed -n 's/^\.*Upload: \([0-9.]*\).*/\1/p' data
1.81
```

- `^\.*` removes preceding dots (any amount)
- `\([0-9.]*\)` capturing group for for the replacement `\1`